# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attachPermissions()

Tags: laravel, entrust

I know this is already an overly discussed problem, but I believe I'm not making the mistake commonly made. I'm getting this error when using the Entrust package for Laravel to create roles and permissions. I'm trying to attach permissions to roles (note, not directly  to models) and got this error. Here's some of the code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;

class RolePermissionSeeder extends Seeder
{
    //assign permissions to roles
    public function run()
    {
        //assign permissions to admin
        $admin =  Role::where('name', 'admin');

        $assignTrainerRole = Permission::where('name', 'assign-trainer-role');
        $removeTrainerRole = Permission::where('name', 'remove-trainer-role');
        $assignTraineeRole = Permission::where('name', 'assign-trainee-role');
        $removeTraineeRole = Permission::where('name', 'remove-trainee-role');
        $attachToTrainer = Permission::where('name', 'attach-to-trainer');
        $detachFromTrainer = Permission::where('name', 'detach-from-trainer');

        $admin->attachPermissions(
            [
                $assignTrainerRole,
                $removeTrainerRole,
                $assignTraineeRole,
                $removeTraineeRole,
                $attachToTrainer,
                $detachFromTrainer,
            ]
        );
// snipped
```

Now, from what I found, generally this error arises when people try to set permissions directly on User or some other model. But I'm not doing that. I'm trying to assign permissions to roles, and still getting this error. Can someone help?

Comment: What does the error says

Comment: Exactly what the title of this post says: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attachPermissions()` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not fetching the permission models properly. You need to call the `first` method like so:

```
$detachFromTrainer = Permission::where('name', 'detach-from-trainer')->first();
```

Also, you can optimize the SQL queries using the wherein clause instead of calling multiple queries like so:

```
$permissions = Permission::whereIn('name', ['name1', 'name2' ...])->get();
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Earlier you had written `get()` and with that I was still getting the error. Can you point me to the link in the docs where the difference between `get()` and `first()` is explained?

Comment: `get` returns an Eloquent collection of models whereas `first` returns the first model or row of the query

Comment: So `get()[0]` would've worked as well? Not considering efficiency, though.